# How to activate PMD and Checkstyle

Tags: sonarqube, checkstyle, pmd

I recently installed SonarQube 5. And I found that PMD and Checkstyle was not installed.

I installed both of them via the update center. But I didn't find a way to activate them in the analyze of the projects.

How can I activate PMD and Checkstyle in SonarQube?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you enabled any PMD and Checkstyle rules in the Quality Profile you are using to analyse?

Comment: I don't know how to do it. This is what I want to do. What I did is just downloading and installing plugins on sonarqube.

Comment: I haven't upgraded to 5 yet but if it works as 4.5 does:
Click Rules on the top nav. 
Click the PMD button in the TOP REPOSITORIES row. 
Click on a rule you want to activate. 
Click the Activate button next to QUALITY PROFILES under the rule description. 

You'll need to run a new analysis with the profile you have changed to see any effect.